# stacked column charts appearing too thin

Tags: highcharts

I have the following issues while working with stacked column charts:

Firstly,look at the following chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/QnuEA/

If you notice the time range is wide, the columns appear too thin. I know that setting pointWidth is one option. But actually the chart should be appearing as they would if the time interval range is narrow as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/QnuEA/1/

The expectation is x-axis interval must adjust itself.

Secondly, for the same chart as above, if the width of the chart is more (say 900 px or so), the x-axis seems to have a lot of empty space before the first tick.

Is there a solution to this? (I am unable to post more than 2 jsfiddle links here.So I am not providing a link for this issue)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange) as `timestamp`

http://jsfiddle.net/QnuEA/3/

Comment: Thanks that helped in solving the issue. But I still do not understand the significance of pointRange.As per the docs, it states "On linear and datetime axes, the range will be computed as the distance between the two closest data points".In both the cases (with and without pointRange), the class interval for x-axis is the same. So if its not too much of a trouble, can you please explain the expected behavior of "pointRange" parameter

Comment: pointRange is needed to calculate minimum distance between ticks, and find a point width value, based on ticks distance.

Comment: I notice that when pointRange is used, the bar is not aligned in par with the tick or label in x-axis. Please see the [link]http://jsfiddle.net/GAUQF/ [link].Another issue I see is, if I hide the legends for 'Minor' and 'Warning', the time label changes to hours instead even on specifying tickInterval. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You can set tickPositions and use formatter to return dates. http://jsfiddle.net/GAUQF/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I just have one more question. When all but one category (say warning) alone is shown, the x and y-axis labels seem to converge and overlap. I have noticed this behavior in all my charts. I cannot set showFirstLabel as false. What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: You need to set [startOnTick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.startOnTick) as true.